# Animating a box-shadow/text-shadow on a circular path?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to use CSS animations to create the effect of a light source pointing down on an object, casting a shadow and moving in a circular motion around it. I've created a snippet below to show where I've gotten to so far.

It's sort-of close but at the moment (because I only have 4 keyframes) it's like the light source is moving along a square path. I'd like it to look like it was moving along a circular path.

The only solution I can think of to come close is to add a bunch of more keyframes and create a (for the sake of simplicity) a dodecagon-shaped path, but is there a simpler solution? Is there a type of timing function I could use to *ease* it into a smoother path? Or could I use some sort of Sass function to automatically calculate the intermediate keyframes?

I should have noted that once I get this working with box-shadows, I'd also like to apply the same method to text-shadows.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
  box-shadow: 50px 50px 5px darkgrey;
  animation: orbit-shadow 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbit-shadow {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 5px darkgrey;
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: -50px 50px 5px darkgrey;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: -50px -50px 5px darkgrey;
  }
  75% {
    box-shadow: 50px -50px 5px darkgrey;
  }
  1000% {
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 5px darkgrey;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to consider rotation for this. Use a pseudo element to avoid rotating the main element:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
  position:relative;
}
.circle::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius:inherit;
  box-shadow: 50px 50px 5px darkgrey;
  animation: orbit-shadow 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbit-shadow {
  100% {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}

body{
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Or you simply rotate the element if you won't have any content:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
  box-shadow: 50px 50px 5px darkgrey;
  animation: orbit-shadow 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbit-shadow {
  100% {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}

body{
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Another idea:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
  position:relative;
}
.circle::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius:inherit;
  background:darkgrey;
  filter:blur(5px);
  animation: orbit-shadow 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbit-shadow {
  0% {
    transform:rotate(0deg)   translate(50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotate(360deg) translate(50px);
  }
}

body{
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

You can also do the same for `text-shadow` with a slightly different animation in order to not rotate the text:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.circle {
  position:relative;
  font-size:40px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.circle::before,
.circle::after{
  content:attr(data-text);
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

.circle::before {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  color:transparent;
  text-shadow:0 0 5px darkgrey;
  animation: orbit-shadow 5s linear infinite;
}
/* the 50px is your offset */
@keyframes orbit-shadow {
  0% {
    transform:rotate(0deg)   translate(50px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotate(360deg) translate(50px) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
body{
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle" data-text="some text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a much simpler solution. I didn't mention it in my original question but this grew out of wanting to apply the same animation to a text-shadow, so I think I'd just got it stuck it my head that I also *had* to use box-shadow so it would translate easily.

But I guess I could just apply your method to text too - just put a duplicate of the text in a pseudo element and animate that in the same way. Thanks!

Comment: @itsViney I am updating with a text shadow solution

Comment: All those examples mess with the scroll bar, but I don't know if there's a solution for it. However, I doubt this will be used somewhere where the scrollbar wasn't there before. However, it can cause content to shift up and down, making it rather annoying. However, I don't know if there's a solution for it... :/ But it looks cool!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel you can increase the margin of the main element to make sure the rotated element will rotate in that area and you will avoid any shift of the content.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Well, I totally forgot about margins ... Would a padding work better, with a `box-sizing: border-box`?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I don't think so because it's not about box-sizing. Margin is more suitable because in all the cases the rotation will make the element go outside unless you apply the padding to a parent element

Comment: @TemaniAfif Makes sense. Thank you for your point of view. Do you think you can add this info to the answer?

Comment: hey brother, do u know if there is a way to appease the SEO gods even if i use an image of text on a circular path instead of [this](https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/) so that the circular text is easier to align, etc?

Comment: @oldboy I think you can always have a hidden text close to your image. Crawler can still see it in the HTML code (not a SEO expert to confirm this btw)

Comment: @TemaniAfif found out that John Mueller himself said that its not really a problem. the only thing the Hs are used for in SEO is to understand the following text or images or content :)